# Python Pandas how to change background color if age is equal to a number?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

How do I change the color of the `Age` column if the condition that the value is equal to `33` is met?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "Nombre": ["Mike", "Jordan", "John"],
        "Age": [33, 45, 20],
        "Lugar": ["Arg", "Pol", "Ind"]
    }
)
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val != 33 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(_color_red_or_green)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to make the color red when you inputs 33, then you need to make this change.

`val == 33`

Instead of

`val != 33`

This is the final code just incase:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "Nombre": ["Mike", "Jordan", "John"],
        "Age": [33, 45, 20],
        "Lugar": ["Arg", "Pol", "Ind"]
    }
)
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val == 33 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(_color_red_or_green)

print(_color_red_or_green(33))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the color of the Age column only, pass the column as `subset=`.

Depending on what you want to color, one of two options are possible:

```py
# change color of values
df.style.applymap(lambda x: f"color: {'red' if x == 33 else 'green'}", subset=['Age'])
```

[image]

```py
# change color of cells
df.style.applymap(lambda x: f"background: {'red' if x == 33 else 'green'}", subset=['Age'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy and convenient by using the functions that already exist, instead of using applymap:

```
(df.style
 .set_properties(subset=["Age"], background="lightgreen")
 .highlight_between(subset=["Age"], color="pink", left=33, right=33)
)
```

(You can of course use [other colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html) if wanted - for background I picked lighter variants of red and green.)

[image]